# get the ID of the inner DIV onclick using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the ID of the inner DIV using javascript. Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5yn2hLv9/8/ .
When i click on First Tab/Second Tab.., the id of the tab should be retrieved in the javascript function getInnerDivId() . please suggest.

Below is sample code:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 100%;height: 100px" tabStrip="true" onclick="getInnerDivId()">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="one" title="First tab" selected="true" id="1" >
        11
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="one" title="Second tab" id="2">
        2222
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" class="one" title="Last tab" id="3">
        333333
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409572/how-do-i-get-the-id-for-a-clicked-tab-in-a-dijit-layout-tabcontainer

Comment: @grizzly - Yes i could not able to get what i need to pass in onClick="doSomething" , the last answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409572/how-do-i-get-the-id-for-a-clicked-tab-in-a-dijit-layout-tabcontainer , as in javascript doSomething(e) is accepting one value. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask your dojo to give you the contents of the selected tab:

Do this in your `click` handler function:

```
function getInnerDivId() {
    var value = this.selectedChildWidget.domNode.attributes["id"].value;
    alert("get inner div iD: " + value);
}
```

See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ncqf5n7c/).

Comment: Did you want the `id` attribute or the contents of the `<div>` (that 2222 etc.)?

Comment: Be sure to remove the `()` from `onclick="getInnerDivId()"` as shown in the fiddle to ensure that `this` is correct in your function.